# horizontal divider or empty line when collpase navbar-collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

below is my current navbar setup...

I want to add a blank line OR horizontal diver between the two `<ul>` within the `nav bar id="navbarsExample04"`

how would I go about adding this blank item or horizontal divider only when the navbar is collapsed?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="..">
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample04"
      (click)="toggleCollapsed()" aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample04" [ngClass]="{'collapse': collapsed, 'navbar-collapse': true}">
      <ul class=" navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link navlinks" href="#">todo</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link navlinks" href="#">todo</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      </ul>

      ## ADD A DIVIDER HERE WHEN COLLAPSED
      <ul class=" navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link navlinks" href="#">contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an `<hr>` with Bootstrap's baked-in responsive display classes to show or hide it as needed?

`<hr class="d-block d-sm-none">`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src=".."></a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample04" aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample04" [ngClass]="{'collapse': collapsed, 'navbar-collapse': true}">
    <ul class=" navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link navlinks" href="#">todo</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link navlinks" href="#">todo</a></li>
    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
    </ul>

    <hr class="d-block d-md-none"> 
      
    <ul class=" navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link navlinks" href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Note: I've modified the collapse point in this example to ensure that it displays collapsed when you run the code snippet.  The `d-md-none` class will likely need to be modified to reflect the correct break-point at which you want to ensure the horizontal line is no longer visible.

Comment: do you have any suggestions for selecting that hr in CSS so I can make style edits?

Comment: You could give it it's own class name or apply an ID to it or target it via `.navbar-collapse hr`, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.show ul:first-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```css
.navbar-collapse.collapse.show ul:first-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="..">
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample04" (click)="toggleCollapsed()" aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample04" [ngClass]="{'collapse': collapsed, 'navbar-collapse': true}">
    <ul class=" navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navlinks" href="#">todo</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navlinks" href="#">todo</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
    </ul>

    ## ADD A DIVIDER HERE WHEN COLLAPSED
    <ul class=" navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link navlinks" href="#">contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much too... though I'm not seeing any change by just adding the style. Did you make any edits to the html that I'm missing? - I attempted changing the color and width to exaggerate but don't see it! :P

Comment: I think it may be with how the style is selecting? Like .navbase-collapse.collapse.show? Not sure about the show? I get the idea though of adding a border to the bottom of the first child of the ul but there are two ul and the first one has two li

Comment: No ul:first-child will select the first ul in the preceding selecor, and also try to keep it in media query such that it only applies when the collapsed menu is shown.

Comment: what exactly am I right about ? still struggling to implement this solution but it looks like I has the potential to be more customized!! lol

Comment: OK. So when I remove the .show the space appears below (but when not collapsed). But when I collapse it the style goes away, regardless of if .show is present or not. Shouldn't it be in both places if I remove .show? What might be causing it to not appear when collapsed! thank you so much

Comment: aka it's not appearing in the collapsed menu... but it is selecting the correct ul!

Comment: You need to add .show, because that class is only applied when you open the collpased menu in mobile(by clicking on the 3 bars icon). That way your style will apply only when you have opened the menu.